# Python subprocess returning exception

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have the following code that has been working until recently:

```
        si = STARTUPINFO()
        si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        env = environ
        self.popen = Popen('python', [path + '\opt_module_v3.py'] + vlist, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, startupinfo=si, env=env)
        lines_iterator = iter(self.popen.stdout.readline, b"")
```

it calls the opt_module_v3.py and returns messages as the child process runs.
When I run the main code, I'm getting the following exception:

```
   self.popen = Popen('python', [path + '\opt_module_v3.py'] + vlist, stdout=PIPE, 
stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, startupinfo=si, env=env)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", 
line 108, in __init__
super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'bufsize'
```

Like I mentioned, this code was working before but I might have stuffed up since I've been working on improvements.
Any clues on what could be happening here?

Comment: Does the error also occur when *not* running this via spyder?

Comment: I don't know. I only have run this via spyder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says the API is:

```
subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=- 1, MORE_ARGS...)
```

This means your command has to be put in a list.

in your code `[path + '\opt_module_v3.py'] + vlist` is interpreted as bufsize

instead of

`self.popen = Popen('python', [path + '\opt_module_v3.py'] + vlist, stdout=PIPE,  stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, startupinfo=si, env=env)`

you should use something like

`self.popen = Popen(['python', [path + '\opt_module_v3.py'] + vlist], stdout=PIPE,  stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, startupinfo=si, env=env)`

I think however you may additionaly need to concatenate your path to a string to make this work

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It turns our I did not need the list with the path. Only the name of the script